# efficiency of a program that checks range of variable vs another that checks values one by one?

Tags: c, performance

Let assume that I have a Boolean function that receives a random number as its argument and then return *True* if the random number is 200, 201 or 202 and return *False* for other values.

The question is which one of the following functions are more efficient?

f1:

```
bool f1(int number) {
    if (number >= 200 && number <= 202)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

f2:

```
bool f2(int number) {
    if (number == 200 || number == 201 || number == 202)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you profile the two code snippets?

Comment: You forgot `if (number < 200) return 0; if (number > 202) return 0; return 1;` or `return (number >= 200) * (number <= 202);`

Comment: An optimizing compiler is likely to generate the same binary code for both.

Comment: @pmg: no, there is a `return false;` for the default case.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I assumed that the compiler optimization is not enabled.

Comment: My guess is pmg has posted "f3:" and "f4:" not correcting "f1:" or "f2:"

Comment: @CinCout Sorry I didn't got your point. May I ask you to explain what did you meant?

Comment: @Abraham: a compiler is always doing *some* optimiization. And what is faster is computer specific. The C11 standard does not speak of them.

Comment: @Abraham: avoid commenting your own question but do edit it.

Comment: @Abraham You should profile, and/or perhaps disassemble your compiler's optimized code generation.  In the case of clang 3.9.1 with O2 optimization, [they are identical](https://godbolt.org/g/mRBD3z), for example.

Comment: @Abraham I meant did you measure (and subsequently, compare) the running time of the two code snippets based on your input(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is which one of the following functions are more efficient?

The [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) does not care about (or speak of) efficiency.

An [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) could generate the same code for both functions (and several of them do).

My GCC 7.1 compiler on Linux/x86-64 generate the same code with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O2 -S`:

```
         .text
         .p2align 4,,15
         .globl  f1
         .type   f1, @function
 f1:
 .LFB0:
         .cfi_startproc
 # abraham.c:3:     if (number >= 200 && number <= 202)
         subl    $200, %edi      #, tmp92
         cmpl    $2, %edi        #, tmp92
         setbe   %al     #, tmp93
 # abraham.c:6: }
         ret
         .cfi_endproc
 .LFE0:
         .size   f1, .-f1
         .p2align 4,,15
         .globl  f2
         .type   f2, @function
 f2:
 .LFB3:
         .cfi_startproc
         subl    $200, %edi      #, tmp92
         cmpl    $2, %edi        #, tmp92
         setbe   %al     #, tmp93
         ret
         .cfi_endproc
 .LFE3:
         .size   f2, .-f2
         .ident  "GCC: (Debian 7.1.0-2) 7.1.0"
         .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

BTW `clang-4.0 -fverbose-asm -S -O2` generates also the same code for both functions, but a different one than `gcc`:

```
          .type   f1,@function
  f1:                                     # @f1
          .cfi_startproc
  # BB#0:
          addl    $-200, %edi
          cmpl    $3, %edi
          setb    %al
          retq
  .Lfunc_end0:
          .size   f1, .Lfunc_end0-f1
          .cfi_endproc
```

And if performance matters that much to you, I recommend defining both functions as `static inline` in some common included header.

If you really care about performance, **benchmark** (after asking the compiler to optimize, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -O2` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). But read more about [*premature optimization*](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), notably the [fallacy of premature optimization](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451). Notice that asking about performance without enabling optimization is contradictory.

Most of the time, you should choose whatever is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I benchmarked it (something you should learn how to do):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat > bench.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

_Bool f1(int number) { return (number >= 200 && number <= 202); }
_Bool f2(int number) { return (number == 200 || number == 201 || number == 202); }

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    int it = c>1 ? atoi(v[1]) : 10000000000;
    int cnt=0;
    for(int j=0; j<10;j++)
    for(int i=0;i<it;i++){
#ifdef F2
        cnt+=f2(i);
#else
        cnt+=f1(i);
#endif
    }
    printf("%d\n", cnt);

}
EOF

gcc -O3 bench.c
./a.out 1
time ./a.out
gcc -DF2 -O3 bench.c
./a.out 1
time ./a.out
```

Couldn't measure a statistically significant difference.
Then I checked the generated [assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/6xRMFp) and gcc generates the same output for both cases, starting at `-O1` (clang isn't so smart):

```
f1:
        subl    $200, %edi
        cmpl    $2, %edi
        setbe   %al
        ret
f2:
        subl    $200, %edi
        cmpl    $2, %edi
        setbe   %al
        ret
```

(looks like a pretty neat optimization trick)

So the answer is the usual: do the more readable thing and leave optimization to the optimizer until you've measured and found it's not doing its job as well as it could.

Comment: You should have `#include <stdbool.h>` and use the code from OP.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I kind of also wanted to compress a "don't do `if(something) return true; else return false;` (it's needlessly verbose) do `return something;`" message into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just see the assembly codes and we do some statistics just from **if**:

```
bool f1(int number) {
011D9160  push        ebp  
011D9161  mov         ebp,esp  
011D9163  sub         esp,0C0h  
011D9169  push        ebx  
011D916A  push        esi  
011D916B  push        edi  
011D916C  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
011D9172  mov         ecx,30h  
011D9177  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
011D917C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
        if (number >= 200 && number <= 202)
011D917E  cmp         dword ptr [number],0C8h  
011D9185  jl          f1+34h (011D9194h)  
011D9187  cmp         dword ptr [number],0CAh  
011D918E  jg          f1+34h (011D9194h)  
            return true;
011D9190  mov         al,1  
011D9192  jmp         f1+36h (011D9196h)  
        return false;
011D9194  xor         al,al  }   


bool f2(int number) {
011D91B0  push        ebp  
011D91B1  mov         ebp,esp  
011D91B3  sub         esp,0C0h  
011D91B9  push        ebx  
011D91BA  push        esi  
011D91BB  push        edi  
011D91BC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
011D91C2  mov         ecx,30h  
011D91C7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
011D91CC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
        if (number == 200 || number == 201 || number == 202)
011D91CE  cmp         dword ptr [number],0C8h  
011D91D5  je          f2+39h (011D91E9h)  
011D91D7  cmp         dword ptr [number],0C9h  
011D91DE  je          f2+39h (011D91E9h)  
011D91E0  cmp         dword ptr [number],0CAh  
011D91E7  jne         f2+3Dh (011D91EDh)  
            return true;
011D91E9  mov         al,1  
011D91EB  jmp         f2+3Fh (011D91EFh)  
        return false;
011D91ED  xor         al,al  
    }
```

For function f1:

- When number equals 200,function f1 calls cmp,jl,cmp,jg,mov,jmp **6** 
  logical operation instructions.
- When number equals 201,function f1 calls cmp,jl,cmp,jg,mov,jmp **6** logical operation instructions.
- When number equals 202,function f1 calls cmp,jl,cmp,jg,mov,jmp **6** logical operation instructions.
- When number is less than 200,function f1 calls cmp,jl,xor **3** logical operation instructions.
- When number is bigger than 202,function f1 calls cmp,jl,cmp,jg,xor **5** logical operation instructions.

For function f2:

- When number equals 200,function f2 calls cmp,je,mov,jmp **4**
  logical operation instructions.
- When number equals 201,function f2 calls cmp,je,cmp,je,mov,jmp **6** logical operation instructions.
- When number equals 202,function f2 calls cmp,je,cmp,je,cmp,jne,mov,jmp **8** logical operation instructions.
- For other numbers,function f2 calls cmp,je,cmp,je,cmp,jne,xor **7** logical operation instructions.

Seems that when return true,the performance is averagely the same since 6+6+6=4+6+8.
But when return false,f1 is better than f2.

Comment: What compiler did you use, for which system, and with which optimizations?

Answer (score -1):

Two more options for you to measure

```
#include <stdbool.h>
bool f3(int n) {
    if (n < 200) return 0;
    if (n > 202) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdbool.h>
bool f4(int n) {
    return (n >= 200) * (n <= 202);
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question.